# Aggregate data from a file

Tags: python, dataframe

A csv file contains the following data : 
[image]

I need to aggregate data which consists of two columns date and vol, where  - 1st data frame
the date is the date in a year on which max volume was traded, and vol is the value of the column 
2nd dataframe
and also date with the highest closing price in a year and the price. in case of multiple need to include all. 
The return value should consist of 2  data frames. An example output is like: 
[image]

Any approach would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the pandas library.

To read the csv use:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(*file_path*)
```

First dataframe:

```
first_df = df[["date", "vol"]]
```

Second dataframe:

```
second_df = df[["date", "close"]]
```